# How is REQUEST_ID_HASH generated in AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine

I would like to use the REQUEST_ID_HASH parameter that appears in os.environ, but I would like more information about it.

How is it generated? Will it be safe to use it like an identifier? Can it be repeated in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being a hash, there's no guarantee it won't repeat - it's too short to guarantee that in any case. And you should use it like a hash, not as an identifier.